# If $i\colon A\to X$ is a cofibration then $1\times i\colon B\times A\to B\times X$ is a cofibration for any space $B$. Is that true?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

In *Algebraic Topology* (Hatcher, pg 14) 
I find: A pair $\left(X,A\right)$
has the homotopy extension property if and only if $X\times\left\{ 0\right\} \cup A\times\mathbb{I}$
is a retract of $X\times\mathbb{I}$. Going out from the situation
that $A$ is a subspace of $X$ and $i$ is its inclusion, this can
be translated into: $i\colon A\rightarrow X$ is a cofibration if and only
if $X\times\left\{ 0\right\} \cup i\left[A\right]\times\mathbb{I}$
is a retract of $X\times\mathbb{I}$. Here $i\left[A\right]=A$. My
question is whether this remains valid in a more general setting reached
by dropping the condition $A\subseteq X$ and letting $i\colon A\rightarrow X$
be a continuous function. Is it true that $i:A\rightarrow X$ is a
cofibration if and only if $i$ is an embedding and $X\times\left\{ 0\right\} \cup i\left[A\right]\times\mathbb{I}$
is a retract of $X\times\mathbb{I}$? In *Topology and Groupoids* (Ronald
Brown, pg 266, 267) I encounter a proof that the conditions are necessary.
But are they sufficient too? If so then, based on it, it can easily
be shown that - if $i\colon A\rightarrow X$ is a cofibration - also $1\times i\colon B\times A\rightarrow B\times X$
is a cofibration for any space $B$ ($r$ retraction $\Rightarrow$
$1\times r$ retraction and $i$ embedding $\Rightarrow$ $1\times i$
embedding). This result can also be found in *Topology and Groupoids*
(pg 268) but this under an extra condition on $B$ (it should be locally
compact) or an extra condition on $i$ (it should be a closed map).
It seems to me that these conditions can be left out. Am I right?

Comment: So, you want to show that $i:A\to X$ is a cofibration if $i$ is an embedding and $X\times\{0\}\cup i[A]\times I$ is a retract? Then it is true. If $i$ is an embedding, we can consider $A$ a subspace of $X$, and $X\times \{0\}\cup A\times I$ being a retract of $X\times I$ indeed implies that each pair of continuous maps, an $f$ on $X\times\{0\}$ and a homotopy $g_t$ on $A\times I$ can be extended to a homotopy on $X\times I$.

Comment: That is correct

Comment: Am I also right in saying that i cofibration implies 1xi cofibration without any extra conditions?

Comment: I don't see a problem. $\text{Id}_B\times i$ is still an embedding, and $\text{Id}_B\times r$ is still a retraction. I don't see why these extra conditions should be necessary.

Comment: If you answer to someone's comment, you should add the string '@Stefan' in the comment, so the person gets notified about your answer. I didn't see your reply to my comment under your last question :) For more information on how this feature works, click the help link next to the comment box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $i$ is an embedding, we can consider $A$ a subspace of $X$, and $X\times \{0\}\cup A\times I$ being a retract of $X\times I$ indeed implies that each pair of continuous maps, an $f$ on $X\times\{0\}$ and a homotopy $g_t$ on $A\times I$ such that they coincide on $A\times\{0\}$, can be extended to a homotopy on $X\times I$. It would be trivial if these two maps $f$ and $g_t$ could always be glued to a single continuous map on the union of their domains. But if this union is a retact $X\times I$, it can be shown that these maps can be glued. A proof can be found in the revised Appendix of Hatcher's book.

Comment: Again: am I also right in saying that i cofibration implies 1xi cofibration without any extra conditions? If so then Ronald Browns asks for conditions that can be left out. And thank you for your answer also.

Comment: I'm not sure. Let me think about it for a while.

Comment: 3 years ago! It was one of my first questions here. Coincidently I came along and noticed that I forgot upvoting.